# Would going from 4gb ram to 8gb increase magento speed on localhost?

Tags: magento, ram

I upgraded my pc from 2.1gh and 2gb ram to dual coure 2.6gh processor and 4GB RAM, magento runs faster but I am still not happy with it (takes 4-6 seconds to open a page).

My memory usage is around 40% alltogether.

Would upgrating to 8GB RAM speed up my magento locally?

Comment: It might, but it's more important to use php.ini to allocate more RAM to PHP, and my.cnf to allocate more RAM to MySQL.  Extra RAM in the machine won't do a thing if PHP and MySQL don't know about it.

Comment: probably it will run faster, but dont forget this is your local machine, on a real server your default setup will die, so Alan is right - you have to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, by itself, No.  The fact that you are sharing resources on a local machine between MySQL and PHP with Magento is inherently slow within itself.   Will you get more throughput?  Probably, but not enough to notice.

You will get more of a performance gain by installing Varnish, and enabling Magento full page caching AFTER you install more RAM.  Magento cache stores itself in the RAM and so does Varnish.  Also make sure you have APC cache installed.  Those three COMBINED with more RAM will make all the difference in the world.

For Varnish .. Give it about 1GB RAM in the VCL settings  ..  Sounds like a lot, but it'll save your life.

For APC, give it at least 256MB of room in the APC settings ...  It would probably behove you to do 512MB if you can afford it.

I am also going to include my PHP.INI `magento optimized` settings as well as my MySQL settings:

```
PHP.INI
 max_execution_time = 18000
 max_input_time = 60
 memory_limit = 1024M
 max_input_vars = 10000
 post_max_size = 102M
 upload_max_filesize =100 M
 max_file_uploads = 20
 default_socket_timeout = 60
 pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
 mysql.cache_size = 2000
 mysqli.cache_size = 2000
 apc.enabled = 1
 apc.shm_segments = 1
 apc.shm_size = 1024M
 apc.num_files_hint = 10000
 apc.user_entries_hint = 10000
 apc.ttl = 0
 apc.user_ttl = 0
 apc.gc_ttl = 3600
 apc.cache_by_default = 1
 apc.filters = "apc\.php$"
 apc.mmap_file_mask = "/tmp/apc.XXXXXX"
 apc.slam_defense = 0
 apc.file_update_protection = 2
 apc.enable_cli = 0
 apc.max_file_size = 10M
 apc.use_request_time = 1
 apc.stat = 1
 apc.write_lock = 1
 apc.report_autofilter = 0
 apc.include_once_override = 0
 apc.localcache = 0
 apc.localcache.size = 256M
 apc.coredump_unmap = 0
 apc.stat_ctime = 0
 apc.canonicalize = 1
 apc.lazy_functions = 1
 apc.lazy_classes = 1
```

And MySQL

```
MY.CNF
key_buffer              = 256M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 32
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 2500
query_cache_limit       = 2M
query_cache_size        = 64M
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M
```

I hope that helps you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can't install all those, haven't even heard of varnish and I can't seem to find apc extension that works with windows 7 x64. I'll get more ram and hope for the best.

Comment: @Zak - are you sure that your MY.CNF config is "magento optimized"??
`key_buffer = 256M` for innodb? how much data you have in myisam tables? `max_connections = 2500` do you really know what it is? and where is the `innodb_` variables for pool size and other things?? timeouts and buffer limits? Varnish storage size not in `VCL settings` but in daemon opts in daemon startup config file. 90% of all problems users have, because they copy-paste configs they found in internet... probably you have copied yours as well...

Comment: `do you really know what this is`?  --  Yes ...  It's a bottle neck at 100 500 and 1000 during this time of year ...  Our customers receive 503 (SQL connection refused) when there is 1000 plus people on the site trying to check out.  --  Maybe before accusing me of copying and pasting you could ask what the application is, how big the store is, and how many concurrent users are expected on the site?

Answer (score 0):

If your memory usage is 40% now, then no. Sufficient RAM does make a difference, but in this case the extra 4 wouldn't make much of a difference.

Magento is quite slow due do its complexity and the fact that it uses thousands of files.

To increase Magento's load speed, try to disable stuff you don't need in the admin section, and perhaps Google for other tips. Also, the load speed *will* differ between different browsers.